# Same script for multiple directories, correct name for directory

Tags: php

```
$images_dir = 'images/';
```

If I want my image directory file to be the current directory what would I replace images/ with. Thank you.

Secondly if I have a script gallery.php which turns all images in the directory into a gallery. I have around 20 directories I would like to turn into a gallery. Is there a way to have the gallery script working in each directory without having to have the script in every directory. For example in each directory having an index.php script

```
call yourdomain.com/gallery.php
```

Or along those lines

Thank you!

Directory configuration

```
1.photos
 2.group photos
  3.1
  3.2
  3.3
  3.etc
 2.single photos
  3.1
  3.2
  3.3
  3.etc
 2.etc
```

Comment: Can we see your directory structure?

Comment: 1) current directory can be found many ways, try `dirname(__FILE__)` 2) I just used [this](http://jdmweb.com/creating-a-simple-image-gallery-with-php-jquery) successfully

Comment: @aligajni I added the directory configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current directory by using

1. `getcwd();` Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php
2. `dirname(__FILE__);` Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php#21138
3. `basename(__DIR__)` Ref https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

You can get the directory name as a query parameter using $_GET and render the corresponding pages instead of having the script in every directory your call will look like

```
call yourdomain.com/gallery.php?id=XXX
```